# How to access methods in arbitrary Angular child component projected with <ng-content>?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm making a dialog with Angular Material that will be a parent component (containing the dialog header and footer) that can then project an arbitrary child component (dialog content) using `<ng-content>/ng-content>`.

**dialog.component.html:**

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Title</h1>
<mat-dialog-content>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="submit()">
    <mat-icon>save</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

**arbitrary-dialog-content.component.html**

```
<dialog>
  <!-- Dialog content here -->
</dialog>
```

What I want to do is to call the arbitrary-dialog-content's save() method FROM the dialog's save() method, so I need to get a reference to the arbitrary component from the parent component. I've tried using @ContentChild but can't get it to work because I don't know which component will be the dialog content until runtime.

Comment: the most comprehensive solution will be using a shared service.  Some kind of save-signal.service that is provided by the dialog wrapper and injected into the dialog and the component within it. Basically you'll be providing the inner component with the context that it might be inside a dialog.

Comment: Ah thanks, where should I provide this service for it to be created and destroyed every time the dialog is opened and closed? So far I only have singleton services that are always available.

Comment: provided by the dialog wrapper. make the injection optional if the inner component might not be in a dialog, and only subscribe to the save signal if the service is inejcted.

Comment: actually im retracting my statement here.  There is an easier way given how you've structured this, added in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an event emitter on your dialog component to communicate between components.

add this in your dialog.ts:

```
@Output() onSubmit = new EventEmitter();

submit() {
  // do whatever you want
  this.onSubmit.next();
}
```

then in your arbitrary component html:

```
<dialog (onSubmit)="save()">
  <!-- Dialog content here -->
</dialog>
```

where save() is your components save function

a shared service would be a more comprehensive solution but this works for this use case.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to use a shared service as you suggest but was tripped up by trying to provide it in the Dialog component. In fact I had to provide it in the arbitrary dialog content component (that is transcluded via <ng-include> in the Dialog component) to make it work.